# Update 2 divs with single click, highlight selected option, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Products we sell have different price attributes, i need to update 2 separate divs on a single click, the attribute name and the price. Also keep the option highlighted.

Ive managed to get the selected option to stay highlighted but i don't know how to pass the values to the divs??

I have no skills with jquery!! :(

basically on the onclick event
I need "Option1" to be put in 'option' div, and "100" to be put in the 'product-price' div

```
<div class="product-options">
<div class="finish" onclick="Option1, 100"> 1 </div>
<div class="finish" onclick="Option2, 200"> 2 </div>
<div class="finish" onclick="Option3, 300"> 3 </div>
<div id="option">{Selected option here}</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id='product-price'>{Selected price here}</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

http://jsfiddle.net/hne006bn/

Comment: can you explain this a little more clearly.  You want the number inside of the div (1,2,3) inside of the product-price div?  you want one of the divs with class "finish" inside of the "option" div?

Comment: sorry, forget about the numbers, they will be replaced by images later on... i just need the text within the link to finish inside the divs

Answer (score 1):

You could add option and price as data-attributes like e.g.

```
<div class="finish" data-option="Option1" data-price="100">
```

and then set the values like this:

```
$('.product-options').on('click','.finish',function () {
 $('.finish').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
 $(".option span").text($(this).data("option"));
 $("#product-price").text($(this).data("price"));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo1kbehk/)

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript solution:

```js
function selector(el, option, price) {

  document.getElementById('option').innerText = option;
  document.getElementById('product-price').innerText = price;

}
```

```css
.finish {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
}
.finish:hover {
  border-color: #000;
}
.finish:focus {
  border-color: #000;
}
.selected {
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-options">
  <button class="finish" onclick="selector(this,'Option1','100')"> <span>1</span>
  </button>
  <button class="finish" onclick="selector(this,'Option2','200')"> <span>2</span>
  </button>
  <button class="finish" onclick="selector(this,'Option3','300')"> <span>3</span>
  </button>
  <div id="option"> <span>{Selected option here}</span>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id='product-price'>{Selected price here}</div>
```

Comment: anyway to keep the selected option highlighted?

Comment: Yes, change the the `.finish` `<div>`s to `<button>` elements.  Then copy the code from the `:hover` selector, and paste it into an identical `:focus` selector.